# Capturing nth url occurence of email body

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I have a string that that has several urls embedded in it and want to capture the nth occurence of urls enclosed with <>.

I currently have `(<.+>)` as my pattern and it captures the 1st url, but I want it to capture nth.  I have tried `(<.+>){n}` but can't get it to work on regex101.

```
match(/(<.+>){3}/g)
```

I am expecting the output to find the 3rd instance of a url enclosed with <>,however on regex101 it does not capture.

The example string is:

```
URL1
<abc.com>
URL2
<cde.com>
URL3
<efg.com>
URL4
<ghi.com>
```

Expected output would be efg.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the pattern `n` number of times with a non-capturing group:

```
/(?:<(?:.|[\r\n])+?>(?:.|[\r\n])*?){2}<((?:.|[\r\n])+?)>(?:.|[\r\n])*/g
```

and `efg.com` will be in `$1`.

If you need to change how many `<url>` come before the desired position then just update `{2}` to whatever you need.

Since you do not have the `/s` modifier available then you need to write out `(?:.|[\r\n])` instead of being able to simply use a period.

The breakdown is:

- `(?:<(?:.|[\r\n])+?>(?:.|[\r\n])*?){2}` - find this pattern two times and ignore the results
- `<((?:.|[\r\n])+?)>` - lazily put everything found in between `<>` into `$1`
- `(?:.|[\r\n])*` - blindly and greedily match the rest of the string so that the pattern cannot recurse. If you don't like this part then you can delete it if you can omit the `/g` modifier

https://regex101.com/r/LWTLgF/4

Comment: it looks like google script does not support the multiline flag `\s` but google sheets does , so instead I extracted the email plainbody into googlesheets and used your pattern to extract the nth url `=REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet1!A4,"(?s)(?:<.+?>.*?){7}<(.+?)>.*")`

Comment: @ghostFishKillah Oh I see. Google Apps Script seems to be a JS-based scripting service so the single line (dotall) `/s` modifier is not available. See my update for a working JS solution.